# Entity graphy binding not working in deep level

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have entity graph like

People ->Student

then in xaml, I have following kind of binding(People is property of VM):

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding People.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox  Text="{Binding People.Student.StudentNo, Mode=TwoWay}" />   <!--  this bounding is not working -->
```

in VM, implementing IEditableObject. I have some code like:

```
public void BeginEdit()
{
   ((IEditableObject)this.People).BeginEdit();
   ((IEditableObject)this.People.Student).BeginEdit();    //this code not working
   //....
}
```

When runing the app, all data bound to People is fine.

All data bound to Student is not working.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the Student property is null on the client side. You need to add the [Include] attribute to the Student property on the server-side, so that it gets taken across to the client side by RIA services. You may also need to add an include for your server-side to retrieve it from the database, depending on how your data-access is written.